# error in my rootpage xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

My Rootpage and the page that controls all my pages, and it is giving an unhandled error when closing, whenever a command to close the error, also when I receive a push notification and I will open the rootpage, an error occurs seconds later . Is something wrong with my command below?

```
public class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    Dictionary<MenuIndex, NavigationPage> Views { get; set; }

    public RootPage()
    {
        Title = "App";

        Views = new Dictionary<MenuIndex, NavigationPage>();

        Master = new MenuPage(this)
        {
            Icon = "ic_menu_white.png"
        };

        NavigateAsync(MenuIndex.Home);
    }

    public void NavigateAsync(MenuIndex id)
    {
        Page newPage;

        if (!Views.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case MenuIndex.Home:
                        Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new HomePage(), "#04518c"));
                    break;
                case MenuIndex.pag1:

                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new TabPage1(), "#04518c"));

                    break;
                case MenuIndex.pag2:

                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new TabPage2(), "#04518c"));

                    break;
                case MenuIndex.pag3:

                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new TabPage3(), "#04518c"));

                    break;

                case MenuIndex.pag4:
                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new TabPage4(), "#04518c"));
                    break;

                case MenuIndex.pag5:
                    Views.Add(id, new ControlNavigationApp(new TabPage5(), "#04518c"));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        newPage = Views[id];

        if (newPage == null)
            return;

        ////pop to root for Windows Phone
        //if (Detail != null && Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
        //{
        //    await Detail.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        //}

        Detail = newPage;

        if (Device.Idiom != TargetIdiom.Tablet)
            IsPresented = false;
    }
}
```

the error is in the rootpage because I did some tests calling other pages and they worked with success. I have the project in ios and it works perfectly

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?  How are we supposed to help you if you can't be bothered to tell us this critical piece of information?

Comment: take a look at the image above